# Detect if a user is using their main account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way to detect the user visiting your page tab app is using their page or their main fb account?

Comment: what is for main account stands ?

Comment: his/her facebook account

Answer (score 2):

If not already tried can you print and check how the Signed Request looks like when a user visits as a page and when a user visits as a Facebook user. The Liked part of Signed Request ideally should not be present for users visiting as a Page. I assume this since when you visit a Page Tab as a page the Liked Button at top right is removed.